# Single ledger to support multiple bakers?

Tags: baking, ledger, setup

Let’s assume that one single ledger controls several keys associated with corresponding addresses enabled for baking.

Is it possible to use this single ledger and a single instance of the signer deamon that would respond to the queries of multiple baker deamons ?

The reason i am asking this is because i believe that currently when bakers maintain multiple bakers managed with ledger, they actually think they need to own multiple physical ledger devices which seem sub-optimal in terms of operational risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot bake for two addresses on a single ledger. it is only authorized to sign for a single address at any given time.

Comment: thanks Mike. Where is the appropriate place on obsidian repo i could add this as feature request ?

Comment: https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos

Answer (score 2):

The ledger maintains a HWM (high watermark) for "double bake protection" - this means it will not sign more than 1 block at a certain height. I do not believe it is possible to maintain multiple HWMs with a single ledger (except for testing period chains), and so you might get in trouble if baker A signed a block for height X+1 just before baker B tries to sign for block X (this might happen in distributed systems).

Comment: Yes, it is not possible -- unless you patch the Ledger baking app. Really, it should not be terribly difficult, but, not easy.